# Функция в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
function ifcodes($a) {
 return $a;
}

echo preg_replace('/ifcodes\((.*?), (.*?)\)/i', ifcodes($1), $page_result);
```

В чём проблема? **syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in ...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такие $1 переменные не разрешены.

Comment: Это регулярное выражение. Уже выяснил ошибку. Правильно так: ifcodes('$1')